# Metal on macOS: Visibility testing behaving incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

In Metal when using the visibility result feature (by invoking `setVisibilityResultMode` on a command encoder), I am using the `MTLVisibilityResultModeBoolean` mode to get a boolean telling me if any fragments passed the visibility tests.

After wrestling with this for a bit, I noticed that I am not actually getting a boolean using this API. I seem to be getting a `uint` counting the number of fragments (pixels??) that passed the visibility test. I'm also not sure about the length of this counter: is it 32-bit? 64-bit?

It actually seems like this is behaving like `MTLVisibilityResultModeCounting`, but I am definitely specifying `MTLVisibilityResultModeBoolean`.

Is this a Metal bug? I am worried it might be a driver bug on my laptop though it is happening in the same way on both GPUs on my MacBook Pro (both the Radeon Pro 460 and the Intel HD Graphics 530).

Here's how I am extracting the `BOOL`:

```
uint32 *resultBuffer = [visibilityResultBuffer contents];
BOOL result = (*resultBuffer != 0);
```

This works correctly in my tests, but I am concerned that this might not work correctly on other GPUs/drivers since it doesn't seem to match the documentation. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515556-setvisibilityresultmode?language=objc), this is working as expected:

> In `MTLVisibilityResultModeBoolean` mode, when a sample passes, the
>   device writes a **nonzero** value to the buffer. If no samples pass, the
>   device writes zero.

Comment: That's my bad @warrenm, I somehow missed this paragraph and assumed it'd be a `BOOL`. Then again, this paragraph does not properly describe the data type being written to. I have filed a documentation bug with Apple.

Comment: Thanks for that report. Can you share the Radar number?

Comment: Sure thing @warrenm, it is 29512495. Thank you for your help. By the way, the text about nonzero value is not where I expected it would be. It is in the Metal Programming Guide under "Graphics Rendering: Render Command Encoder", but when you look up the reference for `MTLVisibilityResultModeBoolean`, all it says is "Indicate whether samples pass the depth and stencil tests."

Comment: @ldoogy Hi, do you find the correct data type eventually? The documentation still misses the data type description.

Comment: @kkpattern The docs have been now updated to correctly indicate the datatype. It is a 64-bit integer.

Comment: @Idoogy Hi, can you give a link to the updated doc? I looked at two pages about visibility result, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515556-setvisibilityresultmode?preferredLanguage=occ and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrenderpassdescriptor/1437942-visibilityresultbuffer?language=objc, none of them indicate the datatype.

Comment: @kkpattern Right here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlvisibilityresultmode/mtlvisibilityresultmodeboolean?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a 64-bit value because of this part of the docs for the `offset` parameter of [`-setVisibilityResultMode:offset:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlrendercommandencoder/1515556-setvisibilityresultmode?language=objc):

> Must be a multiple of 8 bytes.

That alignment would typically only be necessary for an 8-byte (64-bit) type.  So, you should use `uint64_t` rather than `uint32_t`.

Given your code for fetching the value, I assume you're using an offset of 0, is that right?  Otherwise, you're reading from the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, I am reading from offset 0. Combining @warrenm's answer with yours, we can deduce that this is likely a `uin64_t` that should be tested for a non-zero value. Still, I would argue this is poorly documented since then data type isn't explicitly specified.